# Hadoop on periodically generated files

Tags: file, hadoop, input, generated

I would like to use Hadoop to process input files which are generated every n minute. How should I approach this problem? For example I have temperature measurements of cities in USA received every 10 minute and I want to compute average temperatures per day per week and month.

PS: So far I have considered Apache Flume to get the readings. Which will get data from multiple servers and write the data periodically to HDFS. From where I can read and process them.

But how can I avoid working on same files again and again?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider a Big Data stream processing platform like Storm (which I'm very familiar with, there are others, though) which might be better suited for the kinds of aggregations and metrics you mention.

Either way, however, you're going to implement something which has the entire set of processed data in a form that makes it very easy to apply the delta of just-gathered data to give you your latest metrics.  Another output of this merge is a new set of data to which you'll apply the next hour's data.  And so on.

Comment: I was thinking about using Apache Spark which also supports stream processing. Thanks for mentioning Storm. I will check it and see if which one fits better to my case.